# Why is the installation of Babel failing in Electron? And do I need Babel or not?

Tags: javascript, npm, electron, babeljs

I want to use the npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/swipe-detect and get the following error message

```
export default function(target, callback, threshold=150) {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:851:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:633:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:739:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\folder\main.js:22:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:839:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:851:10)
```

I found out that the error is because this is the ES6 syntax. So I've been trying to install babel according to this tutorial. https://www.robinwieruch.de/minimal-node-js-babel-setup/, but I get an error message

```
npm WARN deprecated @babel/polyfill@7.4.4: ðŸš¨ As of Babel 7.4.0, this
npm WARN deprecated package has been deprecated in favor of directly
npm WARN deprecated including core-js/stable (to polyfill ECMAScript
npm WARN deprecated features) and regenerator-runtime/runtime
npm WARN deprecated (needed to use transpiled generator functions):
npm WARN deprecated
npm WARN deprecated   > import "core-js/stable";
npm WARN deprecated   > import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

I also tried several other tutorials and set the environment in .babelrc. The error message still pops up.

Now I read that babel is already included in Electron. [Why is Babel needed in an Electron project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108588/why-is-babel-needed-in-an-electron-project).

I've been searching for two days now and can't find a solution. Why does this error pop up?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Electron/Node version, using the `--experimental-modules` argument may be enough to get it working. (However there may be [issues when you try to package your app](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/13402).)

See https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12011 for some background on using ES modules in Electron. There appear to be various workarounds suggested in that thread.

(Given that the library you want is [only 100 lines](https://github.com/mhfen/swipe-detect/blob/master/dist/index.js), and under a nice liberal MIT license, it might be easier to just clone it, drop the default at the end of that file, and simply export the class.)

Comment: The suggested Github link is too advanced for me. Do you know an up-to-date tutorial to get Babel to work automatically?

Comment: @neolith Sorry, no. I don't use babel, and I don't use those experimental modules. If it was me I'd definitely go with the solution I suggested at the end: fix the library to export a class, instead of using `export default function`.

Comment: I already found the solution. You have to create a babel.config.js instead of .babelrc. Now everything works!